# How to send a request with SNI in k8s ingress or OpenShift route

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-ingress

In OpenShift platform, I created a route for https service as following. The route is https pass-through type, and hostname is "www.https.com".

```
oc get route

NAME           HOST/PORT      PATH      SERVICES      PORT      TERMINATION          WILDCARD
abc-route     www.https.com             abc-service   8888      passthrough          None
```

I have a few of questions for the above, in the document https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html, it mentions the route supports https with SNI and TLS with SNI:

(1) Is hostname "www.https.com" a SNI?

(2)I am wondering how client side send a request with SNI? The above mentioned two scenarios: https with SNI and TLS with SNI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC 3546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3546) and [RFC 6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066):

> 3.1. Server Name Indication
>
> [TLS] does not provide a mechanism for a client to tell a server
> the    name of the server it is contacting.  It may be desirable for
> clients    to provide this information to facilitate secure
> connections to    servers that host multiple 'virtual' servers at a
> single underlying    network address.
>
> In order to provide the server name, clients MAY include an
> extension    of type "server_name" in the (extended) client hello.

Where `client hello` message is a part of [TLS hanshake](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/).

> The 'client hello' message: The client initiates the handshake by sending a "hello" message to the server. The message will include which TLS version the client supports, the cipher suites supported, and a string of random bytes known as the "client random."

1. Is hostname "www.https.com" a SNI?

Any dns name can be a valid SNI. From RFC:

> Currently the only server names supported are DNS hostnames, however
> this does not imply any dependency of TLS on DNS, and other name
> types may be added in the future (by an RFC that Updates this
> document).  TLS MAY treat provided server names as opaque data and
> pass the names and types to the application

2. I am wondering how client side send a request with SNI? The above mentioned two scenarios: https with SNI and TLS with SNI.

From RFC:

> In order to provide the server name, clients MAY include an
> extension    of type "server_name" in the (extended) client hello.
> The    "extension_data" field of this extension SHALL contain
> "ServerNameList" where:
>
> <<redacted for readibility>>

HTTPS with SNI and TLS with SNI are different in a way that HTTPS is L7 and TSL is L4 of OSI model.

This means that SNI can be used for domain based routing not only for http traffic but also for raw tls traffic.